# Openlayers Interaction

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-6

I've been trying to find a way to add a search bar/filter onto my Maps solution, using GeoJSON. I cannot seem to find a example/solution in Openlayers 6, scrolling through the docs and examples on the official site and by googling. Having said that, I assume ol/Geolocation and ol/Control will be invoked.

Does anyone know a good starting point for me to look at how to do this?

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at ol-ext examples, you'll find search controls and bars:
https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/?q=Search